# NullPointerException findViewById()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have a big problem.

On my Samsung Galaxy S2 Android 4.2.2 everything looks fine but when i start it on my Galaxy Tab Android 4.0.2 it throws a NullPointerException by findViewById(R.mainn.seite)

findViewById(R.mainn.seite) always returns null. How is that possible ?
I rebuild my application several times but that didnt solve the problem.

Any idea guys ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ExceptionHandler.register(this, "http://cdu-viersen.de/err/server.php"); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Intent i = getIntent();
    if(i.getIntExtra("von", -1)==1){
        update();
    }
    else if(i.getIntExtra("von", -1)==2){
        einstellungen();
    }

    else{
        checkLaufzeit();

    }
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
         finish();
    }

    ImageView wissen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.wissen);
    wissen.setOnClickListener(choose);
    ImageView dia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.diagnostik);
    dia.setOnClickListener(choose);
    ImageView klinik = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.klinik);
    klinik.setOnClickListener(choose);
    ImageView medi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.medikamente);
    medi.setOnClickListener(choose);
    ImageView rechner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.rechner);
    rechner.setOnClickListener(choose); 
    ImageView notfall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.main.notfall);
    notfall.setOnClickListener(choose);

    TextView seite = (TextView) findViewById(R.mainn.seite);
    seite.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

}
```

My XML File looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
android:id="@+main/main"
tools:context=".Main" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+main/test">
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rand"
    android:id="@+main/mmmm"/>

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_below="@main/mmmm"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rand"/>
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+main/wissen"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@main/mmmm"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_wissen"/>
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+main/medikamente"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@main/mmmm"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@main/wissen"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_medikamente"/>
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+main/rechner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@main/mmmm"       
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@main/medikamente"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_rechner"/>

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+main/klinik"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@main/wissen"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_klinik"/>

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+main/diagnostik"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@main/wissen"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@main/klinik"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_diagnostik"/>
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+mainn/seite"/>

</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+main/main_n"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund_main_links">

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+main/seite_n"/>


    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_leer"
        android:id="@+main/halbrechts"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@main/halbrechts"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_leer"/>




    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+main/q">

        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dienstplan_icon"
        android:id="@+main/dienstplan_n"/>


        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/update_icon"
        android:id="@+main/update_n"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@main/q"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+main/qq">

        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hintergrund_icon"
        android:id="@+main/hintergrund_n"/>


        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"     
        android:src="@drawable/einstellungen_icon"
        android:id="@+main/einstellungen_n"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@main/qq">

        <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/foto_icon"
        android:id="@+main/foto_n"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leiste_unten"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>







<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+main/notfall"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_notfall"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:src="@drawable/schriftzug"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leiste_unten"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why did you name the item mainn/seite when you're always using main for the rest of your items?

Comment: Just for testing reasons if there was a problem with main/seite ...

Lately i found out that this is a general Tablet Problem.
The app does not crash on Phones but on every Tablet i tried.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids should be R.id.something... and should be specified as @+id/something in the xml.
Besides you have a typo in R.mainn.seite

A possible bug source is the layout selector, check if you have more than 1 layout for your Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.
The ids are R.id.... and they are specified as @+id/something ...

What do you mean with the layout selector ? 
I have just 1 layout xml within 2 different RelativeLayouts which are stacked over each other. just one is visible the other one is gone

Comment: You are right...

I have different layouts for different Screen Sizes and i have forgotten to update those for Tablets !

Answer (score 0):

Should it be (R.main.seite)  main not miann

Comment: For test reasons i called the id mainn ... thats not a typo :/

Answer (score 0):

For Inflating a View from the XML, Layout Inflator searches for "@+id".If you are giving something else it will not gonna to find and inflate anything and hence returns null to your object references.....